# Javascript setTimeout multiple and ajax and waiting time

Tags: javascript, time, delay, settimeout

For a long time, I've been trying to make a Javascript function that can work with multiple `setTimeout` and wait until a value is checked.

I've got an input into a form :

```
 <input type="hidden" id="answer_content" value="start" />;

   if($('#answer_content').val()=='start')
    {
     1)create a content with an ajax request that generate a div
     1.1)when the request is finished , $('#answer_content').val('NEW_DIV_ID')
     1.2)then i use this id = NEW_DIV_ID to make another ajax request (move the DIV)
     1.3)Then when it's finished i change $('#answer_content').val('start');
    }
```

Here I need to wait until process 1) is done and DIV element exists.
Then I need to run process 2)3)4)5)6) 

(there are only little change between all process, like div size, border color ....) 

So process are almost the same

I can make it work with multiple `setTimeout` with delay =1000 for the 1st function then delay =2000 for the second .... and 6000 for the last one.

```
   setTimeout(function(){ content_1(); }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){ content_2(); }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){ content_3(); }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function(){ content_4(); }, 4000);
    ......
```

It works, but I want something that can only work if the previous process is finished to avoid error.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to learn how to properly format code within your question.

Comment: Use promises to solve your task. Just google for "JavaScript promise"

Comment: setTimeout is not an appropriate solution for this problem

Comment: Please try to understand the doc before posting this kind of questions (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for answers i think i will try with "JavaScript promise" i found this that looks interesting http://html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises . Now i need to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
window.step = 1;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        switch(step){
            case 1:
                // do something with xhr response (xhr.responseText);
                step++;
                xhr.open("GET", url2, true);
            break;
            case 2:
                // do something with xhr response #2 (xhr.responseText);
                step++;
                xhr.open("GET", url3, true);                
            break;
            case 3:
                // do something with xhr response #3 (xhr.responseText);        
            break;
        }
    }else{
        console.log('error occured in request no#' + step);
    }
}
xhr.open("GET", url1, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a great idea , but in each process i need to wait and get a value (return value) that is generated after an ajax request.If i don't wait the value, the new div will take the place of the previous one.

Comment: It will wait, because it opens next requests only when previous was finished.

Comment: Update : is there a way to use only promise ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.